# Get name of bluetooth connected device to ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Any iOS device can connect to Bluetooth tethering of any other device be it  Android ,Mac anything. So when iOS device connects to Bluetooth tethering , in settings app we can see the name of that device as connected. I Just want that  connected bluetooth name inside my app. Is there any way to get the connected Bluetooth name? The bluetooth may or may not BLE.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following stuff in your code. before getting the list of devices, you must pair those device in your iPad settings.

```
EAAccessoryManager *manager = [EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager];
NSMutableArray *bluetoothPrinters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:manager.connectedAccessories];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `CoreBluetooth framework`.

Coming to connecting to BLE device from iOS devices

and check this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor